# How to fix spinner constantly closing and reopening itself when I try to include items from a Firebase database in its list of items

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-spinner

I'm developing an app for a competition. The app is connected to  a Firebase realtime database, which is organized into some lists of children each with their own string value as follows:

```
category1:
    child1: "string"
    child2: "string"
category2:
    child3: "string"
    child4: "string"
(etc.)
```

I am trying to get the names of these categories and add them to a Spinner dropdown in one of my layouts. When I test out this layout, however, something peculiar happens. If I tap on the Spinner to open the dropdown, it will constantly refresh itself (I can see it continuously closing and reopening). What's even weirder is that sometimes, it will only show a list of two strings (which I add by default) and none of the category names above, but other times it WILL show both of them in the list.

The refresh issue seems to happen regardless of whether or not I try to add the childname strings from Firebase. I can tell it's occurring because the debugger window in Android Studio is constantly spammed with

`D/ViewRootImpl@a8fa8f6[PopupWindow:d00794f]: Relayout returned: old=[286,729][962,1113] new=[286,729][962,1113] result=0x1 surface={valid=true 531823960064} changed=false`

as long as the Spinner dropdown menu is open (in both cases). I tried searching that error up (both whole and in parts) but I could find nothing completely relevant to what I was trying to accomplish.

Here is the code that adds the list to the Spinner (this method is called when the Activity is opened):

```java
    public void onOpen() {
        // This is not the complete method, but the relevant portion of it

        final List<String> categories = new ArrayList<>();
        categories.add(selectionEmpty);
        categories.add(selectionCreateNew);
        dbh.dbref.child("users").child("a_users_uid_goes_here").child("flashcards").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    categories.add(child.getKey());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, categories);
        setSelector.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }
```

And here is the OnItemSelectedListener I assigned to the Spinner:

```java
    AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener selectSet = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long id) {
            String selection = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
            if (selection.equals(selectionEmpty)) onOpen();
            if (selection.equals(selectionCreateNew)) onCreateNewSet();
            else onSelectSet(selection);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    };
```

`onCreateNewSet()` and `onSelectSet(String set)` are currently two empty methods. I don't believe that should have any impact, but just in case it does, they don't do anything at the moment. `onOpen()` is the code snippet above.

This is my first time using Spinner objects, and I'm also new to Android Studio in general (been using it for 6 months), so my apologies if I'm just missing an obvious line of code. To summarize: optimally, the Spinner dropdown should be showing two preset strings and all the category names in the database, and only open once. What's actually happening is that it keeps repeatedly closing/opening and only shows the category names from the database every other time it opens (the preset strings are always there however). I greatly appreciate any help!

I may link a GIF soon of the problem I'm encountering if anyone needs.

UPDATE: It appears that this refresh glitch only happens when I have the default value selected in the dropdown, which is one of the two preset strings. If I select the other one, then this glitch does not occur. Still not sure why it's happening though.

SECOND UPDATE: I've solved it myself, it was a rookie mistake that I'm quite embarrassed to have made. The problem is that in the method `onOpen()` I set the adapter for the Spinner, but then in the Spinner's `AdapterView.onItemSelectedListener` I call `onOpen()` again, leading to a recursive loop that was breaking everything. The fix was to create a duplicate method of `onOpen()` called `onSelectNoSet()` that did the same thing except NOT set the adapter for the spinner, and have the listener call that method instead of `onOpen()`.

**TL;DR** Recursion is bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SECOND UPDATE: I've solved it myself, it was a rookie mistake that I'm quite embarrassed to have made. The problem is that in the method `onOpen()` I set the adapter for the Spinner, but then in the Spinner's `AdapterView.onItemSelectedListener` I call `onOpen()` again, leading to a recursive loop that was breaking everything. The fix was to create a duplicate method of `onOpen()` called `onSelectNoSet()` that did the same thing except NOT set the adapter for the spinner, and have the listener call that method instead of `onOpen()`.

**TL;DR** Recursion is bad